# when i am doing vagrant up i am facing this error regarding could not resolve host

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision, vagrant-plugin

when i am doing vagrant up i am facing this error.

> An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
> message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
> again.
>
> Could not resolve host: vagrant-boxes.cargomedia.ch